yosys works with Verilog but not with SystemVerilog (with the systemverilog plugin)
I've installed yosys. I've installed the systemverilog plugin from https://github.com/chipsalliance/synlig.
I can load the plugin, but then it can't find the top module.
yosys -p "plugin -i systemverilog" -p "read_systemverilog src/main.sv; synth_gowin -top top -json synthesis.json"

 /----------------------------------------------------------------------------\
 |  yosys -- Yosys Open SYnthesis Suite                                       |
 |  Copyright (C) 2012 - 2024  Claire Xenia Wolf <claire@yosyshq.com>         |
 |  Distributed under an ISC-like license, type "license" to see terms        |
 \----------------------------------------------------------------------------/
 Yosys 0.40 (git sha1 a1bb0255d65, clang++ 15.0.0 -fPIC -Os)

-- Running command `plugin -i systemverilog' --

-- Running command `read_systemverilog src/main.sv; synth_gowin -top top -json synthesis.json' --
    -noassert
        ignore assert() statements
    -debug
        alias for -dump_ast1 -dump_ast2 -dump_vlog1 -dump_vlog2

    -dump_ast1
        dump abstract syntax tree (before simplification)

    -dump_ast2
        dump abstract syntax tree (after simplification)

    -no_dump_ptr
        do not include hex memory addresses in dump (easier to diff dumps)

    -dump_vlog1
        dump ast as Verilog code (before simplification)

    -dump_vlog2
        dump ast as Verilog code (after simplification)

    -dump_rtlil
        dump generated RTLIL netlist

    -defer
        only read the abstract syntax tree and defer actual compilation
        to a later 'hierarchy' command. Useful in cases where the default
        parameters of modules yield invalid or not synthesizable code.
        Needs to be followed by read_systemverilog -link after reading
        all files.

    -link
        performs linking and elaboration of the files read with -defer

    -parse-only
        this parameter only applies to read_systemverilog command,
        it runs only Surelog to parse design, but doesn't load generated
        tree into Yosys.

    -formal
        enable support for SystemVerilog assertions and some Yosys extensions
        replace the implicit -D SYNTHESIS with -D FORMAL

1. Executing SYNTH_GOWIN pass.

1.1. Executing Verilog-2005 frontend: /Users/justinzaun/local/brew/bin/../share/yosys/gowin/cells_sim.v
Parsing Verilog input from `/Users/justinzaun/local/brew/bin/../share/yosys/gowin/cells_sim.v' to AST representation.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\LUT1'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\LUT2'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\LUT3'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\LUT4'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\__APICULA_LUT5'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\__APICULA_LUT6'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\__APICULA_LUT7'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\__APICULA_LUT8'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MUX2'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MUX2_LUT5'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MUX2_LUT6'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MUX2_LUT7'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MUX2_LUT8'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFS'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFSE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFR'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFRE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFP'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFPE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFC'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFCE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFN'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFNE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFNS'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFNSE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFNR'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFNRE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFNP'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFNPE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFNC'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFNCE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\VCC'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\GND'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IBUF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OBUF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\TBUF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IOBUF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\ELVDS_OBUF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\TLVDS_OBUF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OSER4'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OSER8'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OSER10'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OVIDEO'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OSER16'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IDES4'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IDES8'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IDES10'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IVIDEO'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IDES16'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IDDR'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IDDRC'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\ODDR'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\ODDRC'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\GSR'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\ALU'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\RAM16S1'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\RAM16S2'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\RAM16S4'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\RAM16SDP1'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\RAM16SDP2'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\RAM16SDP4'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\SP'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\SPX9'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\SDP'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\SDPX9'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DP'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DPX9'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\rPLL'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\PLLVR'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OSC'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OSCZ'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OSCF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OSCH'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OSCW'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OSCO'.
Successfully finished Verilog frontend.

1.2. Executing Verilog-2005 frontend: /Users/justinzaun/local/brew/bin/../share/yosys/gowin/cells_xtra.v
Parsing Verilog input from `/Users/justinzaun/local/brew/bin/../share/yosys/gowin/cells_xtra.v' to AST representation.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MUX2_MUX8'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MUX2_MUX16'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MUX2_MUX32'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MUX4'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MUX8'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MUX16'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MUX32'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\LUT5'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\LUT6'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\LUT7'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\LUT8'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DL'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DLE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DLC'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DLCE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DLP'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DLPE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DLN'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DLNE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DLNC'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DLNCE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DLNP'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DLNPE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\INV'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IODELAY'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IEM'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\ROM16'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\ROM'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\ROMX9'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\rSDP'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\rSDPX9'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\rROM'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\rROMX9'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\pROM'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\pROMX9'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\SDPB'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\SDPX9B'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DPB'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DPX9B'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\PADD18'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\PADD9'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MULT9X9'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MULT18X18'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MULT36X36'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MULTALU36X18'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MULTADDALU18X18'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MULTALU18X18'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\ALU54D'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\BUFG'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\BUFS'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\PLL'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\TLVDS_IBUF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\TLVDS_TBUF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\TLVDS_IOBUF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\ELVDS_IBUF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\ELVDS_TBUF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\ELVDS_IOBUF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MIPI_IBUF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MIPI_IBUF_HS'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MIPI_IBUF_LP'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MIPI_OBUF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MIPI_OBUF_A'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\I3C_IOBUF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\CLKDIV'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DHCEN'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DLL'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DLLDLY'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\FLASH96K'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\FLASH256K'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\FLASH608K'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DCS'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DQCE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\FLASH128K'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MCU'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\USB20_PHY'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\ADC'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\BANDGAP'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\CLKDIV2'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DCC'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DHCENC'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\EMCU'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\FLASH64K'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\FLASH64KZ'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\I3C'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IODELAYA'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IODELAYC'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\SPMI'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IODELAYB'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\PLLO'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DCCG'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\FLASH96KA'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MIPI_DPHY_RX'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\CLKDIVG'.
Successfully finished Verilog frontend.

1.3. Executing HIERARCHY pass (managing design hierarchy).
ERROR: Module `top' not found!

all that is in src/main.sv is a simple top module to count on some leds:
module top
(
  input CLK,
  output [5:0] LED
);

reg [23:0] wait_counter = 'd0;
reg [5:0] ledCounter = 0;

assign LED = ~ledCounter;

always @(posedge CLK) begin
  if (wait_counter < 13500000) begin
    wait_counter <= wait_counter + 'd1;
  end
  else begin
    wait_counter <= 'd0;
    ledCounter <= ledCounter + 'd1;
  end
end

endmodule

This same code WILL build with just Verilog, but I'm trying to get it to build as SystemVerilog as I want to start using SystemVerilog features.
yosys -p "read_verilog src/main.sv; synth_gowin -top top -json synthesis.json"   

 /----------------------------------------------------------------------------\
 |  yosys -- Yosys Open SYnthesis Suite                                       |
 |  Copyright (C) 2012 - 2024  Claire Xenia Wolf <claire@yosyshq.com>         |
 |  Distributed under an ISC-like license, type "license" to see terms        |
 \----------------------------------------------------------------------------/
 Yosys 0.40 (git sha1 a1bb0255d65, clang++ 15.0.0 -fPIC -Os)

-- Running command `read_verilog src/main.sv; synth_gowin -top top -json synthesis.json' --

1. Executing Verilog-2005 frontend: src/main.sv
Parsing Verilog input from `src/main.sv' to AST representation.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\top'.
Successfully finished Verilog frontend.

2. Executing SYNTH_GOWIN pass.

2.1. Executing Verilog-2005 frontend: /Users/justinzaun/local/brew/bin/../share/yosys/gowin/cells_sim.v
Parsing Verilog input from `/Users/justinzaun/local/brew/bin/../share/yosys/gowin/cells_sim.v' to AST representation.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\LUT1'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\LUT2'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\LUT3'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\LUT4'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\__APICULA_LUT5'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\__APICULA_LUT6'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\__APICULA_LUT7'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\__APICULA_LUT8'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MUX2'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MUX2_LUT5'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MUX2_LUT6'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MUX2_LUT7'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\MUX2_LUT8'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFS'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFSE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFR'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFRE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFP'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFPE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFC'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFCE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFN'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFNE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFNS'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFNSE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFNR'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFNRE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFNP'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFNPE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFNC'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DFFNCE'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\VCC'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\GND'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IBUF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OBUF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\TBUF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IOBUF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\ELVDS_OBUF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\TLVDS_OBUF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OSER4'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OSER8'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OSER10'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OVIDEO'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OSER16'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IDES4'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IDES8'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IDES10'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IVIDEO'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IDES16'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IDDR'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\IDDRC'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\ODDR'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\ODDRC'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\GSR'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\ALU'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\RAM16S1'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\RAM16S2'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\RAM16S4'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\RAM16SDP1'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\RAM16SDP2'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\RAM16SDP4'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\SP'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\SPX9'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\SDP'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\SDPX9'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DP'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\DPX9'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\rPLL'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\PLLVR'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OSC'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OSCZ'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OSCF'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OSCH'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OSCW'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\OSCO'.
Successfully finished Verilog frontend.

*** REMOVED A BUNCH OF LOGS ***

2.30. Printing statistics.

=== top ===

   Number of wires:                130
   Number of wire bits:            177
   Number of public wires:         130
   Number of public wire bits:     177
   Number of ports:                  2
   Number of port bits:              7
   Number of memories:               0
   Number of memory bits:            0
   Number of processes:              0
   Number of cells:                114
     ALU                            54
     DFFE                            6
     DFFR                           24
     GND                             1
     IBUF                            1
     LUT1                           12
     LUT2                            1
     LUT4                            3
     MUX2_LUT5                       4
     MUX2_LUT6                       1
     OBUF                            6
     VCC                             1

2.31. Executing CHECK pass (checking for obvious problems).
Checking module top...
Found and reported 0 problems.

2.32. Executing JSON backend.

End of script. Logfile hash: 691ee5878c, CPU: user 0.22s system 0.01s
Yosys 0.40 (git sha1 a1bb0255d65, clang++ 15.0.0 -fPIC -Os)
Time spent: 28% 20x read_verilog (0 sec), 11% 1x abc9_exe (0 sec), ...

What am I doing wrong?

I have seen development environments that supported SV but not as a top level.  Don't know if this is your issue; maybe worth investigating.

Coincidentally, I just tried this today for the first time and ran into the same issue. I think that the read_systemverilog command isn't even running. It's possible that the systemverilog plugin is only compatible with older yosys versions, but that's utter speculation. Haven't tried it yet. I'd recommend looking into sv2v as well.

@JohnM - I was thinking the same thing. I read something, old, that said it used a patched yosys as well.

@JohnM - This is what I'm using for now. I would still like to get yosys to work directly though.



mkdir -p ./build;
sv2v src/main.sv > ./build/transpile.v
yosys -p "read_verilog build/transpile.v; synth_gowin -top top -json synthesis.json";
rm -rf ./build

This plugin no-longer works as a plugin, must patch yosys. See https://github.com/chipsalliance/synlig/issues/2430#issuecomment-2090773819
